# Why is my .desktop file not working?

Tags: bash, gnome, wine, 20.04, .desktop

I have recently installed and configured two games on my desktop using WINE. After creating .desktop files in /usr/share/applications/, I noticed the applications wouldn't run when I tried using them.

Here are the contents of my .desktop files:

**osu.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=osu!
GenericName=osu!
Exec=wine /home/geixco/Games/osu!/osu.exe
Icon=/home/geixco/Games/osu!/osu.png
Terminal=false
```

**ut99.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=UT99
GenericName=UT99
Exec=wine /home/geixco/Games/Unreal Tournament 1999/System/UnrealTournament.exe
Icon=/home/geixco/Games/Unreal Tournament 1999/ico.png
Terminal=false
```

When I tried executing the commands in terminal myself, I ran into these errors:

```
geixco@ubuntu-NE56R:~$ wine /home/geixco/Games/osu!/osu.exe
bash: !/osu.exe: event not found
geixco@ubuntu-NE56R:~$ wine /home/geixco/Unreal Tournament 1999/System/UnrealTournament.exe
wine: cannot find '/home/geixco/Unreal'
```

Despite being formatted the same as the Exec field, the icons work just fine. How do I fix the formatting so that the commands work properly?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it helps solve the problem, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special characters and spaces are throwing things off.

Try these...

**osu.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=osu!
GenericName=osu!
Exec=wine "/home/geixco/Games/osu/osu.exe"
Icon="/home/geixco/Games/osu/osu.png"
Terminal=false
```

---

**ut99.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=UT99
GenericName=UT99
Exec=wine "/home/geixco/Games/Unreal Tournament 1999/System/UnrealTournament.exe"
Icon="/home/geixco/Games/Unreal Tournament 1999/ico.png"
Terminal=false
```

**postnote**: Placing the .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications/` makes them available to all users. Best to move them to `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: osu.desktop still comes up with `bash: !/osu.exe: event not found`, and the icon shows up as unknown. Unfortunately, I can't test the ut99.desktop because I accidentally deleted in a sudo nautilus session...

Comment: @geixco Try it now. Report back.

Comment: Just tried. Bash finally accepts the command, but WINE doesn't.
`wine: cannot find '/home/geixco/Games/osu\!/osu.exe'`

Comment: @geixco Try it now.

Comment: `bash: !'/osu.exe: event not found`
:')

Comment: @geixco Sheesh. Please rename the enclosing folder to `osu` and edit the .desktop file again, as in my answer.